# Countdown Timer keeps starting over on button press

Tags: android

Okay, so I have a countdown timer, and my app requires the user to tap a button numerous times, however the timer starts ON that button tap. My problem is:

I have a 10 second countdown timer that starts at the press of the button, but instead of just continuing down to 0, it restarts at 10 everytime the user taps the button. How do I make it so when the user taps it the first time, it keeps counting down?

My code:

```
private Button tapBtn;
TextView cm;

tapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Tap);
cm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);

final CountDownTimer aCounter = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            cm.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             cm.setText("Time's Up!");
         }
      };
      aCounter.cancel();

tapBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scr = scr - 1;
            TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
            Score.setText(String.valueOf(scr));
            aCounter.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make it so that if the user has already started the timer, subsequent button presses don't restart it from the first tap? If so, all you should have to do is put an if statement in your onclick that checks to see if the timer is still counting down, i.e. check and see if the current time is greater than 0 on the counter.

Edit: here's code

```
final CountDownTimer aCounter = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

         private long timeLeft;

         public long getTimeLeft() {
            return timeLeft;
         }

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

            cm.setText("Time Left: " + timeLeft);

         }

         public void onFinish() {
             cm.setText("Time's Up!");
         }
      };
      aCounter.cancel();

tapBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (aCounter.getTimeLeft() == 0) {
               scr = scr - 1;
               TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
               Score.setText(String.valueOf(scr));
               aCounter.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see what you're saying. I just don't know how to apply it in code :(.

Comment: @MikeGaro I added some code. Let me know if it works for you. If you like my answer please remember to select it as an answer. It looks like you have yet to accept any.

Comment: I'm getting:

    The method getTimeLeft() is undefined for the type CountDownTimer

in the line 'if (aCounter.getTimeLeft() == 0) { .  the 'getTimeLeft' is underlined in red and it says that. Also it says 'getTimeleft' variable is never actually used?

Comment: Yea. The way I just threw in that new method in there isn't going to work. You're going to have to create a subclass of CountDownTimer, and add the method and private variable there.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm still unsure how to apply it. I'm sorry :(, i don't mean to be a pain. I know that I have to let it know that if it's not at 00:00 then don't 'start' the timer again. I just don't know how write it in perfect code lol, i'm sorry man :(((((

Comment: It seems like you keep asking people to just give you code. Why don't you try researching a bit before relying on everyone else to solve your problems? Here's a pretty simple tutorial/example on something called 'inheritance', which is what you'll need to learn to solve your problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to create a flag that gets set on the first tap and have the onclick event flip the flag on the first click, and put the timer start inside of an if statement that only occurs if the flag hasn't been set.

Comment: damn, i'm kinda lost. I'm new to coding, so i've been googling everything and tweeking it to my liking. Would one of you mind shooting me a line of code? Thanks so much.

I understand, what you mean, I just don't know how to apply it.